# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException - Retrofit Call

Tags: android, retrofit2

I am trying to call a `PUT` method on my `Retrofit` instance:

```
Response<UpdateUserProfileResponse> response = App.getService().updateUserProfile(//A good 26 parameters).execute();
```

The parameters in the `updateUserProfile()` are a mixture of String, Boolean and one `List<MyObject>`. When I call this method, I get the following error:

```
Throwing new exception 'length=238; index=1366' with unexpected pending exception: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=238; index=1366
06-28 21:53:12.458 3928-6610/com.subby.development A/art: art/runtime/thread.cc:1329]   at retrofit2.Response
```

**Update**

I found the issue. There are two `RealmList<BackgroundString>` which are causing the issue. When I evaluate both RealmLists, I get:

`Unable to evaluate the expression method threw 'java.lang.IllegalStateException' exception.`

Comment: Apparently not good enough 26 parameters. You certain the error's at this line?

Comment: Yeah the next line of the error points to that. I'll update the answer with the variables then.

Comment: Cool, do so, because somewhere there hides the troublesome array in question :)

Comment: I found the issue as i've updated the question but still not sure why it's doing that? I am passing two Lists which are either Empty or it has data inside it. But why is it showing that error?

Comment: I also had a similar issue caused by using Instant Run in Android Studio I think. I resolved it by doing Build > Clean Project.

Answer (score 33):

For anyone else stumbling upon this question, the actual issue most likely is this: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37078190
i.e. Instant Run on Marshmallow/23 (and maybe even 24) has issues in the android runtime. Android 8/26+ have an official fix, but for most people disabling Instant Run should be sufficient.

also re:
https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/1486
https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/1506

Comment: I got to this after 2 hours of search. Thanks! else I would have wasted more time.

Comment: Still facing the issue. Any other solution ?

Answer (score 17):

Throwing new exception 'length=1120; index=2310' with unexpected pending exception: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1120; index=2310

It's working fine in Android Nougat and Oreo but i was facing the issue in Marshmallow.I just fixed it by turning off the "Instant run". Do it by going to
File->Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Instant Run and disable the instant run option

Comment: Still facing the issue. Any other solution ?

Comment: which version of android studio are you using @JiteshPrajapati ?

Answer (score 10):

I am also facing same issue:

Disable `Instant Run` solves the problem.

Follow path below:

> Setting ->Build,Execution,Development -> `Instant Run`

Comment: Still facing the issue. Any other solution ?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using this in background **thread or any new Handler().postDelayed()** then use this API call in **UI Thread**.

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    APIClient.getAPIService().getEffects(Constants.apiKey).enqueue(new Callback<POJOCLASS>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(Call<POJOCLASS> call, Response<POJOCLASS> response) {
                            if (response.body().error.msg == null) {

                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(Call<POJOCLASS> call, Throwable t) {

                        }
                    });
                }
            });
```

try this code

Answer (score 0):

wrap your code into try catch block, like i did for example

```
 Call<JsonObject> call = null;
        try
        {
            call = apiService.getUserList(getUsersListRequestModel);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Wapping code inside a `try-catch` block isn't considered as a good practice.

Answer (score 0):

When I faced the issue I was using next versions of the libraries:

```
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0'
```

gradle:

```
com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.3
```

and was initializing `Retrofit` instance like this:

```
Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(URL)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .build()
```

But changing of `GsonConverterFactory` initializing to `GsonConverterFactory.create(GsonBuilder().create())` solved the problem:

```
Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(URL)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(GsonBuilder().create()))
        .build()
```