# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException - Retrofit 2.4.0 Call

Tags: java, android, retrofit2, indexoutofboundsexception

I am trying to hit `POST` call using `retrofit`. It's working fine on some devices but crash on **Nexus 5** with OS version `6.0.1`.

But now I am facing an exception

> art/runtime/thread.cc:1344] Throwing new exception 'length=1903;
>   index=3147' with unexpected pending exception:
>   java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1903; index=3147

I know on SO there are so many questions But nothing is helpful for me.
I tried everything as per given posts like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38086208/2196176), [this](https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/1486) and [this](https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/1506) etc. Some guys resolved this issue by disabling the **Instant Run**. But it's not working for me.

I am using these dependencies for retrofit:

```
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.10.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.4.0'
```

This is my project level gradle file:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4'
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
```

This is my API call where I am getting `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`

```
APIClient.getAPIService().getEffects(Constants.apiKey).enqueue(//callback);
```

This is my API interface where the call has declared:

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("/getEffects")
Call<GetEffectResp> getEffects(@Field("apikey") String apikey);
```

If someone resolves this please help me to figure out.

TIA

Comment: post the related code too.

Comment: @VivekMishra I have already added the code where i get the exception **APIClient.getAPIService().getEffects(Constants.apiKey)**. What do you need let me know? So, I can update the question.

Comment: could you please share JSON  response.?

Comment: @AtifAbbAsi App is crashed before the API hit.

Comment: @Sunny what about other API are they working fine.?

Comment: @AtifAbbAsi Yes exactly Signup and login API's are working fine.

Answer (score 1):

I have also faced same issue. In my case i resolve it using the `JsonElement` instead of the **Pojo class**.

Below is the callback. You can try it...

```
APIClient.getAPIService().getEffectsInternal(Constants.apiKey).enqueue(new Callback<JsonElement>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<JsonElement> call, Response<JsonElement> response) {

                   Log.e("",""+response.body());


                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<JsonElement> call, Throwable t) {

                }
            });
```

I hope it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

I use next version of the libraries:

```
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0'
```

When I faced the error I was creating `Retrofit` instance like this:

```
Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(API_ENDPOINT)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .build()
```

Changing of `GsonConverterFactory` initializing solved the problem:

```
Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(API_ENDPOINT)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(GsonBuilder().create()))
        .build()
```